# Does Dart have childSelector in event function like jQuery on()?

Tags: dart, dart-html

Does Dart have childSelector in event function like jQuery on()? Because I want fire contextmenu event only if mouse hover specific element type.

This is my javascript code.

```dart
 var $contextMenu = $("#context-menu");
 $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
 $contextMenu.css({
     display: "block",
     left: e.pageX,
     top: e.pageY });
   return false;
 });
```

But I don't know how to check if hover "table tr" in my Dart code.

```dart
 var body = querySelector('body');
 var contextMenu =querySelector('#context-menu');
 // fire in everywhere 
 body.onContextMenu.listen((e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    contextMenu.style.display = 'block';
    contextMenu.style.left = "${e.page.x}px";
    contextMenu.style.top  =  "${e.page.y}px";     
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter events :

```dart
body.onContextMenu.where((e) => e.target.matchesWithAncestors("table tr"))
    .listen((e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   contextMenu.style.display = 'block';
   contextMenu.style.left = "${e.page.x}px";
   contextMenu.style.top  =  "${e.page.y}px";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the following:

`$("body")` gives you a set of elements that does not change. The `.on(..., 'sub selector') however  is actually bad, because it checks the subselector against the target of the event EVERY TIME for every event.

I see two solutions here:

The first is to select all children and add the event listener to all of the elements:

```
var body = querySelector('body');
body.querySelectorAll('table tr')... onContextMenu...
```

But this will not work if you insert tr into the table later.

The other way is to check the .target of your event and see if it's a tr and if its in your table. I hope this already helps. If you need more detailed help let me know!

Regards
Robert

Comment: Hi all! Both matchesWithAncestors or check by using (e.target as Element).tagName are work. Thanks for your hint.